# Changing class of linked image if it has been visited using jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, class, rollover, visited

I have a series of linked rollover images using jQuery. Once the link has been clicked I would like the rollover images to change their class from 'rollover' to 'rollover2' so that I get a different set of images. Here is the jQuery for the rollover images:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("img.rollover").hover( 
function() { this.src = this.src.replace("_off", "_on"); 
}, 
function() { this.src = this.src.replace("_on", "_off"); 
});
$("img.rollover2").hover( 
function() { this.src = this.src.replace("_off2", "_on2"); 
}, 
function() { this.src = this.src.replace("_on2", "_off2"); 
});
});
```

Here is the code for the linked images:

```
<a href="Mod1/index.html" target="_blank">
<img src="images/watch_off.png" class="rollover" />
</a>
```

The initial rollover works great, but I was trying to use the visited links plugin from [here](http://remysharp.com/2008/02/25/visited-plugin/) to trigger the change in the class name of any linked images to 'rollover2':

```
<script src="js/jquery.visited.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#links a').visited(function () {
  // hides the li element
  $(this).img.removeClass("rollover");
  $(this).img.addClass("rollover2");
});
</script>
```

This doesn't seem to work. Might any of you be able to help me out with this?

Answer (score 2):

you can use [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method, try this:

```
$('#links a').visited(function () {
  $(this).find('img').removeClass("rollover");
  $(this).find('img').addClass("rollover2");
});
```

Comment: no luck with that. I wonder if there is a better way to change the class of visited links than using that jQuery visited plugin. I noticed the demo of the plugin didnt even seem to work for me.

Comment: why don't you use css `:visited` selector?

Comment: How might I go about that? I can't put conditionals in css, right?

Answer (score 0):

This should work,

```
$(this).find('img').removeClass("rollover");
$(this).find('img').addClass("rollover2");
```

or better,

```
 $(this).find('img').removeClass("rollover").addClass('rollover2');
```